# How can I fix this error? Xcode generated Myproject-Swift.h error

Tags: swift

I have problems with compiling.

This is in the auto-generated "MyProject-swift.h" file.

```objectivec
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC3sfw17ContentKeyManager")
@interface ContentKeyManager : NSObject <AVContentKeySessionDelegate>
- (void)contentKeySession:(AVContentKeySession * _Nonnull)session didProvideContentKeyRequest:(AVContentKeyRequest * _Nonnull)keyRequest;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

> Type argument 'AVContentKeySession' must be a pointer (requires a '*')
> Insert ' *'

> Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'NSObject'
> Remove '<AVContentKeySessionDelegate>'

> Unknown class name 'AVContentKeySessionDelegate'; did you mean 'AVContentKeySession'?
> Replace 'AVContentKeySessionDelegate' with 'AVContentKeySession'

Code:

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class ContentKeyManager: NSObject, AVContentKeySessionDelegate {
```

XCode 14.0.1 Swift 5

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Is `AVContentKeySessionDelegate` visible in Objective-C and Objectiveee-C Compatible? Same `AVContentKeySession` for?

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed, but `AVContentKeySessionDelegate` is in `AVFoundataion`, it's not a custom class/delegate. So I guess it's missing the AVFoundation import.

Comment: I added the AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h import and two protocols to the .m file, which messes up my project-swift.h file, the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

This code compiles on Xcode14:

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class ContentKeyManager: NSObject, AVContentKeySessionDelegate {
  func contentKeySession(_ session: AVContentKeySession, didProvide keyRequest: AVContentKeyRequest) {
  }
}
```

Can you elaborate more about why you are getting the error?